# Wordpress CMS изменение контента

Tags: php, html, cms

Так есть изменить там надо кое что.Пароль и логин есть cpanel.Так с помощью FTP я зашел и увидел что там wordpress cms. Так вот все есть cpanel,ftp т.д нету только логин и пароль от wp-admin.Есть 2 вопроса как себя добавить как админа и как вообще изменить контент ничего не понял там буду блогадарен

Comment: phpmyadmin + md5 online. заходите (логин и пароль гдето в конфиге wp), ищите таблицу с пользователями, добавляете в нее себя с паролем прогнанным где-нибуть онлайн через md5.

Comment: А тут пароли начинаются с $ ну в online- md5 пароль по другому тут 5 пользователей есть и шифровано как $P$B т.д

Comment: да, там что-то другое, вот есть кодировщик http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4

Comment: Есть такая проблема я сделал и зашел через wp-admin там есть ошибка:You do not have sufficient permissions to access this admin page.

Reason: The current user doesn't have the "read" capability that is required to access the "Əsas Lövhə" menu item.

Comment: права надо поставить как у админа в таблице

Comment: Друг конечно извини могу надоеть просто очень помогаешь. Тут есть user_activation key user login user pass user name display name user url user status т.д как узнать кто админ и как сделать

Comment: вот есть инструкция, админы оказывается прописываются в отдельной таблице. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/

Comment: все все я сделал! как ответ напишите все это поставлю маркер блогадарю вас!!